# Using inner class in outer class (ActionBarSherlock)

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, inner-classes

I have an  `outer class` that `extends ListActivity` . I also want to `extend  SherlockActivity` , so I created an inner class in outer class.

- Issue 1: `innerclass myinnerclass  = new innerclass ();` is used for extending inner and outer classes together. **It works with android 4.0 BUT NOT 2.3**
- Issue 2: Even if that works with 4.0 , I could not use `getSupportActionBar().setTitle("test");` in outer class

  > ```
  >  public class outerclass extends ListActivity { // or extends another activity
  >     innerclass myinnerclass  = new innerclass ();
  >     public class innerclass extends SherlockActivity  {
  >             public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  >                 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        
  >                 getSupportActionBar().setTitle("test");
  >               }      
  >     }
  > ```

Comment: why dont you use `SherlockListActivity` check doc here http://klassm.github.io/andFHEM/javadoc/com/actionbarsherlock/app/SherlockListActivity.html

Comment: it works for ListActivity, but what if we extend different types of activities / our manual activities etc. Are there anyway for them ?